# How Gradient passed by tf.py_func

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

This is Faster R-CNN implement in tensorflow.
The [proposal_layer](https://github.com/smallcorgi/Faster-RCNN_TF/blob/master/lib/networks/network.py#L159) is [implement](https://github.com/smallcorgi/Faster-RCNN_TF/blob/master/lib/rpn_msr/proposal_layer_tf.py) by python

i am curious about if gradient can pass by `tf.py_func`
the weights and biases are keep changing
so I think the gradient deliver back successful

Then I do a small test

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def addone(x):
    # print type(x)
    return x + 1

def pyfunc_test():
    # create data
    x_data = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None])
    y_data = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None])

    w = tf.Variable(tf.constant([0.5]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

    y1 = tf.mul(w, x_data, name='y1')
    y2 = tf.py_func(addone, [y1], tf.float32)
    y = tf.add(y2, b)

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_data))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
    train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for step in xrange(201):
            ran = np.random.rand(115).astype(np.float32)
            ans = ran * 1.5 + 3
            dic = {x_data: ran, y_data: ans}
            tt, yy, yy1= sess.run([train, y1, y2], feed_dict=dic)
            if step % 20 == 0:
                print 'step {}'.format(step)
                print '{}, {}'.format(w.eval(), b.eval())

        test = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x_data:[1]})
        print 'test = {}'.format(test)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyfunc_test()
```

Variable `b` keep changing, but `w` keep the value after initialize and never change

`sess.run(tf.gradients(loss, b), feed_dict=dic)` get value
`sess.run(tf.gradients(loss, w), feed_dict=dic)` get `{TypeError}Fetch argument None has invalid type <type 'NoneType'>`

I know some questions suggest use `tf.RegisterGradient` and `gradient_override_map`
but I can't find these in the faster rcnn repo(link on top of post)
am I do something wrong or missing something so that `w` is freeze

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gradient of `py_func` is `None` (just check `ops.get_gradient_function(y2.op)`). There's this [gist](https://gist.github.com/harpone/3453185b41d8d985356cbe5e57d67342) by @harpone which shows how to use gradient override map for py_func.

Here's your example modified to use that recipe

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def addone(x):
    # print(type(x)
    return x + 1

def addone_grad(op, grad):
    x = op.inputs[0]
    return x

from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
import numpy as np

# Define custom py_func which takes also a grad op as argument:
def py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=True, name=None, grad=None):

    # Need to generate a unique name to avoid duplicates:
    rnd_name = 'PyFuncGrad' + str(np.random.randint(0, 1E+8))

    tf.RegisterGradient(rnd_name)(grad)  # see _MySquareGrad for grad example
    g = tf.get_default_graph()
    with g.gradient_override_map({"PyFunc": rnd_name}):
        return tf.py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=stateful, name=name)

def pyfunc_test():

    # create data
    x_data = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None])
    y_data = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None])

    w = tf.Variable(tf.constant([0.5]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

    y1 = tf.mul(w, x_data, name='y1')
    y2 = py_func(addone, [y1], [tf.float32], grad=addone_grad)[0]
    y = tf.add(y2, b)

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_data))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
    train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    print("Pyfunc grad", ops.get_gradient_function(y2.op))
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for step in range(10):
            #            ran = np.random.rand(115).astype(np.float32)
            ran = np.ones((115)).astype(np.float32)
            ans = ran * 1.5 + 3
            dic = {x_data: ran, y_data: ans}
            tt, yy, yy1= sess.run([train, y1, y2], feed_dict=dic)
            if step % 1 == 0:
                print('step {}'.format(step))
                print('{}, {}'.format(w.eval(), b.eval()))

        test = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x_data:[1]})
        print('test = {}'.format(test))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyfunc_test()
```

Comment: Thanks your answer, I know the gist by harpone, but I can't find `tf.RegisterGradient` in the faster rcnn repo, so I wonder know if it possible deliver gradient only by py_func without `tf.RegisterGradient`, or skip the layer

Comment: `tf.RegisterGradient` is part of core TensorFlow, try `help(tf.RegisterGradient)` in Python shell

Comment: ok, I figure out, the gradient of `tf.py_func` in Faster R-CNN repo can't deliver, but some of loss calculated by the value before `tf.py_func`. So even the gradient of `tf.py_func` is none, the weights before `tf.py_func` can update.

Comment: and why reture `x` in `addone_grad` rathar than return `grad`?

Comment: You could return grad, that was just an example of non standard gradient